# Select rows from last week for tally

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a sql chunk that calculates how many times each name appears in a data table:

```
$picksql = mysql_query("
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy1 AS player FROM data_match) UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy2 AS player FROM data_match) UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy3 AS player  FROM data_match)UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy4 AS player  FROM data_match)UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy5 AS player FROM data_match) UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy6 AS player  FROM data_match)
    ORDER BY player;");

$picksql2 = mysql_query("SELECT player,count(distinct match_id) as numberofgames FROM data_match  t1 JOIN (
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy1 AS player FROM data_match) UNION 
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy2 AS player FROM data_match) UNION 
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy3 AS player  FROM data_match) UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy4 AS player  FROM data_match)UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy5 AS player FROM data_match) UNION
    (SELECT DISTINCT guy6 AS player  FROM data_match)
    ORDER BY player) t2 
    WHERE t2.player=t1.guy1 OR t2.player=t1.guy2 OR t2.player=t1.guy3 OR t2.player=t1.guy4 OR t2.player=t1.guy5 OR t2.player=t1.guy6  GROUP by t2.player");
```

The thing is, I'm trying to only select matches from the past week. Where would I put in something like:

```
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

In order to make it only select from the past 2 weeks? Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. :D

Comment: `... OR t2.player=t1.guy6  AND  date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY GROUP by t2.player`

Comment: It seems to change the numbers, but only a small bit. When I use the query `SELECT * FROM data_smite_match2 WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY`, I get around a third of the games I have total, and using your way only gets me to about 2/3. Thank you though!